Mismatch Between IDs in Instagram Webhooks and Graph API
I'm facing an issue with the Instagram Graph API where the ID in the webhook data doesn't match the ID returned from the /me endpoint.
I use the /me endpoint to get the Instagram Business ID:
https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username
This returns 12345 and my username.
When an Instagram user sends a message, the webhook data contains a different recipient ID (67890), which doesn't match the stored ID (12345).
Example Webhook:
{
  "object": "instagram",
  "entry": [
    {
      "time": 67890,
      "id": "12345400796128930",
      "messaging": [
        {
          "sender": { "id": "981149143905198" },
          "recipient": { "id": "67890" },
          "timestamp": 1735516966810,
          "message": {
            "mid": "1bfkwjeb1jk43b1jk43bkj",
            "text": "hello hello"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

The recipient ID (67890) corresponds to the user who authorized my app but is not the same as the ID from the /me endpoint.
Is Instagram sending an ID that can't be looked up via the access token?  This ID (67890) is persistent across multiple webhook requests.
